# Configuring Application Load Balancer with ports

Tags: amazon-web-services, port, load-balancing, amazon-elb

Here is my situation. I have an application load balancer open to three ports: 80, 443, and 8850. For my listeners I have 80 being redirected to 443, my 443 listener is being forwarded to a target group configured on port 80, and my port 8850 listener is also being forwarded to the same target group configured on port 80.

What I am trying to achieve is for my port 8850. When accessing this port it is being forwarded to the target group configured on port 80. I need this port to stay on port 8850. I know I need a second target group configured to point at 8850 instead of 80 but am unsure how to configure port 80 to point to this "new" target group. I am only allowed one listener for each port. Any ideas how I can accomplish being able to access 8850 would be helpful.

Comment: Please correct me if i have understood wrong :-
1) you want listener at port 8850 to another target group configured at port 8850?
2)what do you mean by "how to configure port 80 to point to this "new" target group. "

Answer (score 1):

This was almost impossible to figure out. In my case I was trying to set up a TCP port for socket connections so my server could accept regular traffic on port 80 and additional traffic on another port. Hopefully this helps someone who's been trying to figure this out for 6 hours.

First, go to EC2/Load balancers. Then, open the target groups page:

[image: open target groups]

Next, create a target group:

[image: create target group]

Make sure to choose a target type of instances:

[image: choose instances]

Choose port 8850:

[image: port 8850]

**Important! For the health check, set it to port 80 if 8850 is going to be a TCP port, otherwise settings will get reset by AWS after a period of health check failures. AWS cannot do a health check on a TCP port apparently.**

On the next screen, select the instance that is the target of the forward (your ec2 instance). Mine is blank here to hide sensitive info:

[image: select instance]

Once you've selected it, you will need to click "include as pending below":

[image: include]

Finally, your target group just needs to be added in a listener on the application load balancer. Open the load balancers screen and select your load balancer:

[image: load balancers]

Choose "add listener" under the listeners tab:

[image: add listener]

Select port 8850 and choose the target group you just created (note: even for TCP, choose HTTP (or HTTPS is you're using secure sockets). If the target group doesn't show up, you didn't associate the correct instance or choose the right VPC:

[image: add listener settings]

Answer (score 0):

->In Applicaiton load balancer, the application server won't see ip-address of the client directly.

-> In order to access port and IP address, it can be seen in **HTTP headers**.Application Load Balancers and Classic Load Balancers add X-Forwarded-For, X-Forwarded-Proto, and X-Forwarded-Port headers to the request.

**The X-Forwarded-Port request header helps you identify the destination port that the client used to connect to the load balancer**.[Http headers load balancer aws docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/userguide/how-elastic-load-balancing-works.html#request-routing).

> **So you can add a rule, where condition will be HTTP header value would be your port number and choose your action how you want to redirect or forward.**[tutorial for using HTTP header](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-advanced-request-routing-for-aws-application-load-balancers/)